# No me ejecuta una consulta en Derby (JSP/JSF)

Tags: base-de-datos, jsf, apache

Buenas tardes,

Estoy desarrollando un proyecto Universitario el cual consiste en crear una pagina de hoteles usando Java Server Pages. Yo estoy utilizando el framework Server Faces. Quiero hacer que la plantilla base del programa, el cual contiene un buscador (Un Form), ordene al form que contiene el index, actualizarse con los resultados de la búsqueda. Como base de datos utilizo Derby.

Ahora, mi consulta por algun motivo no esta funcionando... tengo entendido que Derby no es la misma cosa que SQL en diferentes detalles. El codigo de mi Frijol es este:

```
package Beans;

import javax.inject.Named;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import Database.GestorDB;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
/**
 *
 * @author SEMINARIO
 */
@Named(value = "portada")
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class Portada {
    private String html;
    private String fechaE, fechaS, localidad;
    private int personas, Pmostrado;
    public Portada() {
       fechaE=null;
       fechaS=null;
       localidad=null;
       personas=0;
       Pmostrado=0;
    }

    public void setHtml(String htm){html=htm;}
    public void setFechaEntrada(String dato){fechaE=dato;}
    public void setFechaSalida(String dato){fechaS=dato;}
    public void setLocalidad(String dato){localidad=dato;}
    public void setPersonas(int dato){personas=dato;}  
    public void setPortada(){
        String []hoteles = new String[10];
        String []nombh = new String[10];
        String []localid = new String[10];
        html=null; html="<table>";
        ResultSet rs;
        String query = "SELECT HOTELES.NOMBRE AS A, HOTELES.IMGHOTEL, HOTELES.DESCRIPCION, LOCALIDADES.NOMBRE AS B FROM HOTELES INNER JOIN LOCALIDADES" 
                + " ON LOCALIDADES.IDLOCALIDADES = HOTELES.LOCALIDADES_IDLOCALIDADES";
        try {
            rs = GestorDB.getConsulta(query);
            int i = 0;
            while(rs.next()){    //en nombre de juan manuel         
               nombh[i] = rs.getString("A");
               hoteles[i] = rs.getString("IMGHOTEL");
               localid[i] = rs.getString("B");
               i++;
            }
           int a = 0;
            for(int c=0; c < 3; c++){
                html += "<tr>";          
                for(int f=0; f < 3; f++){
                      html += "<td><div id=\"HotP\"><b><p style=\"text-align:center;font-style:italic;color:red\">"+ nombh[f+a] +"</p></b>"+
                        "<img src=\"resources/images/"+ hoteles[f+a] +"\" style=\"width:160px;height:70px;border:1px solid gray;\"/><br>"
                        + "<span style=\"color: darkblue;text-align: center;\">" + localid[f+a] +"</span></td>";                       
                }
                html += "</tr>";
                a+=3;
            }
            html += "</table>";
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Portada.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        System.out.println(html);
        Pmostrado=1;
    }

    public void setBusqueda() throws SQLException{
        String parametros[] = {localidad,String.valueOf(personas)};
        int f = 0;
        ResultSet rs = null;
        String query = "SELECT HOTELES.NOMBRE, HOTELES.IMGHOTELES, LOCALIDADES.NOMBRE AS NOMBRE1 FROM ((DISPONIBILIDAD INNER JOIN TARIFAS ON TARIFAS.[DISPONIBILIDAD_IDDISPONIBILIDAD] = DISPONIBILIDAD.IDDISPONIBILIDAD) INNER JOIN HOTELES ON TARIFAS.[HOTELES_IDHOTELES] = HOTELES.IDHOTELES) INNER JOIN LOCALIDADES ON HOTELES.[LOCALIDADES_IDLOCALIDADES] = LOCALIDADES.IDLOCALIDADES WHERE (LOCALIDADES.NOMBRE LIKE '%Mexico%' AND TARIFAS.PERSONAS >= 3) AND DISPONIBILIDAD.N_DISPONIBLE > 0";
        html=null; html = "<table>";
        try{
            rs = GestorDB.getConsulta(query);
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Portada.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        if(rs != null){
           while(rs.next()){
            if(f == 0) html += "<tr>";
            html += "<td><div id=\"HotP\"><b><p style=\"text-align:center;font-style:italic;color:red\">"+ rs.getString("A") +"</p></b>"+
                    "<img src=\"resources/images/"+ rs.getString("IMGHOTEL") +"\" style=\"width:160px;height:70px;border:1px solid gray;\"/><br>"
                    + "<span style=\"color: darkblue;text-align: center;\">" + rs.getString("B") +"</span></td>";
            f++;
            if(f == 2){ html += "</tr>"; f=0;}
           }
           html += "</table>";
           System.out.println(html);
        }
    }

    public String getHtml(){return html;}
    public String getFechaEntrada(){return fechaE;}
    public String getFechaSalida(){return fechaS;}
    public String getLocalidad(){return localidad;}
    public int getPersonas(){return personas;}     
    public String getBusqueda() throws SQLException{
        if(Pmostrado !=0) setBusqueda();
        else setPortada();
        return html;
    }
}
```

Para los que se marean al ver tanto código, en si el problema empieza aquí:

```
 String query = "SELECT HOTELES.NOMBRE, HOTELES.IMGHOTELES, LOCALIDADES.NOMBRE AS NOMBRE1 FROM ((DISPONIBILIDAD INNER JOIN TARIFAS ON TARIFAS.[DISPONIBILIDAD_IDDISPONIBILIDAD] = DISPONIBILIDAD.IDDISPONIBILIDAD) INNER JOIN HOTELES ON TARIFAS.[HOTELES_IDHOTELES] = HOTELES.IDHOTELES) INNER JOIN LOCALIDADES ON HOTELES.[LOCALIDADES_IDLOCALIDADES] = LOCALIDADES.IDLOCALIDADES WHERE (LOCALIDADES.NOMBRE LIKE '%Mexico%' AND TARIFAS.PERSONAS >= 3) AND DISPONIBILIDAD.N_DISPONIBLE > 0";
```

Empece haciendo consultas parametrizadas con el formulario, pero decidí por motivos de prueba hacer una consulta sencilla. El error arrojado por Netbeans (org.apache.derby) es el siguiente:

```
Error de sintaxis: Encountered "[" at line 1, column 126.
```

Si gustan, puedo dejar el stack completo... pero es claro que derby se queja de un error de sintaxis. ¿Que error tendria mi consulta?, sera que en derby se escribiría distinto?

Comment: ¿Por qué estás armando la respuesta HTML dentro de una variable `String`? La idea de JSF es que él, como framework MVC, provea todos los componentes necesarios para generar el HTML de manera más sencilla, principalmente cuando se trata de HTMl dinámico. Sobre tu pregunta, debe ser sobre esto en el query: `TARIFAS.[DISPONIBILIDAD_IDDISPONIBILIDAD]`.

Comment: Gracias por ese comentario de generar html con el framework. La verdad que es la primera vez que utilizo ese framework y no lo conocia mucho.. ya entiendo lo que dices...